# Boosting with highly correlated features

Tags: random-forest, boosting, bagging

I have a conceptual question. My understanding is, that Random Forest can be applied even when features are (highly) correlated. This is because with bagging, the influence of few highly correlated features is moderated, since each feature only occurs in *some* of the trees which are finally used to build the overall model.

My question: With boosting, usually even smaller trees (basically "stunps") are used. Is it a problem to have many (highly) correlated features in a bagging approach?

Answer (score 10):

Actually, your understanding of a random forest is not 100 percent correct. Variables are sampled per split, not by tree. So every tree has access to all variables.

In general, tree based models are not too strongly affected by highly correlated features. There are no numeric stability issues as with least squares. You can easily add a variable twice without numeric problem. Note however that most *interpretability* tools like split importance or partial dependence plots *are* affected by multicollinearity. So be careful with them in such cases.

Comment: OKay, thanks. But with bagging, there is some kind of ensamble learning going on. My understanding is that bagging kind of does the trick when it comes to highly correlated independent variables...

Comment: Bagging is about rows, not about columns. So if you e.g. bag a linear regression and there are two identical columns, every model will have collinearity issue.